# Apache is viewing php files as texts

Tags: apache, ubuntu

After I updated to php7.0 now it's viewing the files, I firstly thought it was in apache itself, but i have reinstalled it, what could be the problem..?

ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

Install PHP 7 and the Apache PHP module as follows:

```
apt-get -y install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Then restart Apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Another possible reason could be short open tag. Configure php.ini files related line as: `short_open_tag = On` and restart php service.

Comment: those are already installed, and `systemctl ` isn't a command.

Comment: For the first, everything is installed, the second ( it's not a command).

Comment: looks like on ubuntu 15.04 it should be service not systemctl. try this @AhmedAlaa